# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.api.gax.rpc.StubSettings$Builder com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.SubscriberStubSettings$Builder.setBackground

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Im am trying to use google cloud pubsub with actuator but when I call /actuator/health the program throws the following exeption:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.api.gax.rpc.StubSettings$Builder com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.SubscriberStubSettings$Builder.setBackgroundExecutorProvider(com.google.api.gax.core.ExecutorProvider)'
    at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.DefaultSubscriberFactory.buildSubscriberStubSettings(DefaultSubscriberFactory.java:398) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.DefaultSubscriberFactory.createSubscriberStub(DefaultSubscriberFactory.java:339) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate.getSubscriberStub(PubSubSubscriberTemplate.java:527) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate.pullAsync(PubSubSubscriberTemplate.java:209) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate.pullAsync(PubSubSubscriberTemplate.java:259) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate.pullAsync(PubSubTemplate.java:147) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicator.pullMessage(PubSubHealthIndicator.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(PubSubHealthIndicator.java:100) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(PubSubHealthIndicator.java:95) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:85) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:44) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:99) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:61) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:71) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:305) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:388) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Line that throws error is that, saying that method does not exists.

[DefaultSubscriberFactory.java#L398](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/main/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spring/pubsub/support/DefaultSubscriberFactory.java#L398)

```java
    ExecutorProvider executor = getExecutorProvider(subscriptionName);
    if (executor != null) {
      subscriberStubSettings.setBackgroundExecutorProvider(executor);
    }
```

I tried to modify versions of the libs without success.

Spring Boot version 2.3.1.RELEASE

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core'
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:3.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub'
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a given fact; it only uses `com.google.api.gax.core.InstantiatingExecutorProvider`:

See [`SubscriberStubSettings.java`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/main/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/stub/SubscriberStubSettings.java)

Comment: Yeah, but this source code is for google library, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you haven't provided a single line of code and I'm not a clairvoyant (it's not reproducible alike that). This could well be a version conflict, which only would function with nicely matching versions. Maybe check the issue tracker - or try to build the example project? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues ...feel free to post your own answer, in case you may find something of relevance.